# Apply filter on one column and replicate the values in another column for the same filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current **Pandas dataframe** with two columns (A, B) as below

Column A = G, H, A, B, D, A, A

Column B = apple, banana, peach, guava, orange, grapes, strawberry

On Column A, I want to first filter out only '**A**'

Next I want to update '**A**' in the corresponding fields of Column **B** as described below retaining the other values in B

Desired **Pandas dataframe**

Column A = G, H, A, B, D, A, A

Column B = apple, banana, **A**, guava, orange, **A**, **A**

Hope my question is clear and understood. Requesting assistance with the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: `import numpy as np`;`df['Column B'] = np.where(df['Column A'].eq('A') ,df['Column A'], df['Column B'])` conditional assignment is pretty simple and easily found in documentation and the [10 minutes to pandas guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) - voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
df.loc[df['A']=='A','B']='A'
```

Result df:[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Pandas.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is what you need to filter on where column A is A, then change the corresponding values in B to A.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['G', 'H', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
                   'B' : ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'guava', 'orange', 'grapes', 'strawberry']})

df.loc[df['A'] == 'A', 'B'] = 'A'

    print(df)

   A       B
0  G   apple
1  H  banana
2  A       A
3  B   guava
4  D  orange
5  A       A
6  A       A
```